# Why can Enumerable.Except be used on a string array in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

**Example**

Here is a code example I found at the [Pete on Software](http://www.peteonsoftware.com/?p=59) blog:

```
var listThree = new string[] { "Pete", "On", "Software" };  
var listFour = new string[] { "Joel", "On", "Software" };  
stringExcept = listThree.Except(listFour);
```

The code compiles and runs. So far so good.

**Question**

However, I don't understand why it works.

So, can anyone explain why I can use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) on a string array?

Perhaps, it will be clear to me if someone could explain how to read the signature of `Enumerable.Except` and give me a code example:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second
)
```

**What I know**

I know the concepts of generics and extension methods. But obviously not good enough to understand the code example above. I have also already used some basic Linq queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Except` is an extension method which extends any type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  This includes the [System.Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) type which implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

The note on the linked page explains why the docs don't show `System.Array` implementing `IEnumerable<T>`

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the Array class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore are not visible to the documentation build tools. As a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class, and there are no reference topics for interface members that are accessible only by casting an array to the generic interface type (explicit interface implementations). The key thing to be aware of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that members which add, insert, or remove elements throw `NotSupportedException`.

Answer (score 2):

It just says that if you have an `IEnumerable` of a given type `TSource` in this case `string` you can Except it with another `IEnumerable` of the same type and get a third `IEnumerable` of the same type back. The key point is that the two `IEnumerable` inputs have to be the same (and obviously the return will be of the same type).

Answer (score 2):

An array of T (or say a `T[]`), is also an `IEnumerable<T>`. In your question, T is `System.String`. And `Enumerable.Except` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, so it's also working for a `string[]`. And `stringExcept = listThree.Except(listFour);` equals to

```
stringExcept = Enumerable.Except(listThree, listFour).
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will match the `TSource` argument to string as a string array implements the `IEnumerable<string>` interface and thus matches the first argument of the extension method. So the answer is two things:

- `string[]` implements `IEnumerable<string>`
- The compiler is intelligent enough to infer the generic arguments

Answer (score 0):

The Except method returns the elements in the first enumerable that do not also appear in the 
second enumerable.  So in the case you specified, the result would be `{"Pete", "Joel"}`.

In this case, thinking in terms of string arrays is perhaps a red herring. It might be more advantageous to think in terms of object equality ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx).

The Microsoft documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx